# Configuring Contact Builder in Marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have a DE which can have multiple entries of a contact, based on the type of webinars he attends.The primary key for the DE is combination of email address and webinar name. ***Also i want to use the DE as a root***.  In data designer if i connect the contact key to the email address of my DE, only one entry of any contacts(one email address) will enter my journey. How can i configure the data designer so that i can have all the entries of the same contact with same email address enter my journey. Is there a way to link contact key to a combination of fields in DE.

[image]

Comment: So how do you envision utilizing a `1:n` relationship in your journey?

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/contact_builder/data_designer/), Root data sources should be 1:1 with Contacts:

> A root relationship represents a one-to-one relationship between a
>   contact record and a data extension that acts as a source for contact
>   information. A root relationship can only take place between the
>   contact record and a single data extension. That contact record
>   relates via the contact key or contact ID to the data extension. The
>   data extension used as part of the root relationship can contain only
>   one row per individual contact. Each row in a root relationship
>   represents a contact, and you cannot link to multiple rows for a
>   single contact in a root relationship.

If you'd like to leverage the 1:n relationship in your journey, perhaps you can build a `WebinarAttendees` DE that is 1:1 with `Contact Key`.  Then you can link your `WebinarDEFinal` to that DE.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Adam, appreciate your help. I have a small question based on your above comment. You mentioned **'Then you can link your WebinarDEFinal to that DE'** unable to figure out how can we link the two data extension (WebibarAttendees and WebinarFinal). Could ypu plz specify the steps. TIA.

Comment: You define the relationships in Contact Builder.